# CakePHP Syntax error or access violation

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.1

I have following relationships
Users(id, name, email, ...)
movies(id, name, ...)
users_watchlists(id, user_id, movie_id)

Its a HABTM relationship.

**Error**

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not
>   unique table/alias: 'UsersWatchlist'
>
> SQL Query: SELECT `UsersWatchlist`.`id`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`first_name`, `UsersWatchlist`.`last_name`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`display_image`, `UsersWatchlist`.`email`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`password`, `UsersWatchlist`.`birthday`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`gender`, `UsersWatchlist`.`group_id`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`banned`, `UsersWatchlist`.`created`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`modified`, `UsersWatchlist`.`id`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`first_name`, `UsersWatchlist`.`last_name`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`display_image`, `UsersWatchlist`.`email`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`password`, `UsersWatchlist`.`birthday`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`gender`, `UsersWatchlist`.`group_id`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`banned`, `UsersWatchlist`.`created`,
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`modified` FROM `reelstubs`.`users` AS
>   `UsersWatchlist` JOIN `reelstubs`.`users` AS `UsersWatchlist` ON
>   (`UsersWatchlist`.`movie_id` = 4 AND `UsersWatchlist`.`user_id` =
>   `UsersWatchlist`.`id`)
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp

**Users Model**

```
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
       'UsersWatchlist' => array(
            'className' => 'Movie',
            'joinTable' => 'users_watchlists',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'movie_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
  );
```

**Movie Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'UsersWatchlist' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'users_watchlists',
        'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'deleteQuery' => '',
        'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

**UsersWatchlist**

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Movie' => array(
        'className' => 'Movie',
        'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Not sure why its trying to fetch name etc from UsersWatchlist

Comment: Sounds like you have two tables that have the same "name".

Comment: I noticed that you posted many other questions with the same model structure, but containing the corrections I mentionned in my answer. So can I conclude that my answer helped you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not sure why its trying to fetch name etc from UsersWatchlist

Because you have a model for the relation datatable called `UsersWatchlist` and you named the relations between User and Movie with the same name.

Try to update those names:

**User Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
   'Movie' => array(
   ...
```

**Movie Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
   'User' => array(
   ...
```

These keys are used as aliases in the SQL query, making it fail in this case.

By the way, if you use the `users_watchlists` datatable only to maintain a link between Users and Movies (for example if you don't store any properties about the relation), you can probably just get rid of the `UsersWatchlist` model.